# Why is this span column being offset?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a website with Twitter bootstrap, a screenshot is [image: here]

This sometimes happens and I've not managed yet to nail the exact circumstances... Sometimes I try to nest a `<div>` using `row-fluid` but I get the results shown in the screenshot.

The child `span6` div has a `left-margin` I can't seem to get rid of.

I would like to be able to nest **two** `span6` `<div>` inside that `row-fluid` `<div>`... It should be possible, no?

Comment: Do you want the community to debug your markup by the screenshot? Provide a fiddle or the code at least.

Comment: I thought it would be some simple silly mistake I was making... but ok.

Comment: I'll try and reproduce the issue on a simple jsfiddle... But I was really this was a very common mistake a lot of people do and **someone would come over and say**: *ah, I've had it happen to me many times, you just need to blah blah blah*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build the layout inside a `.row-fluid`, Bootstraps applies to every `.spanN` a `margin-left`:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 2.76243%;
}
```

And then, it overrides this property to the `:first-child`:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

As you are including that `<h2>` before the first `.span6`, it becomes the second element and `:first-child` selector doesn't affect it.
So, to solve your issue, get that heading out of the `.row-fluid` where you place your spans.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found out the answer.

The culprit was that `<h2>` heading within the **parent div** but outside the **children divs**.